# Is there an element/block in OpenModelica to use a signal remotely without wiring?

Tags: openmodelica

Is there an element/block in OpenModelica to which we connect a signal and then use the element somewhere else to connect to the rest of the model to prevent too much wiring in the model drawing. The equivalent block in Matlab/Simulink would be "Goto" and "From" blocks as shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression from the Modelica Standard Library might be what you are looking for.

[Screenshot of graphical implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW6iT.png)

Notice you don't need a Goto element. You can simply reference the signal source across multiple hierarchies through dot notation (in the case depicted: sine.y).

Comment: Thanks! This perfectly works and helps to get rid of long wired feedbacks etc.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could do something like that using hidden connections (create a connection and remove the graphical line, but keep the connection), but there is nothing built into OMEdit or the Modelica specification to do it automatically.